# Short story about a boy raised in a "bubble" who becomes the smartest person alive

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi

I'm trying to recall a story that must be sixty or seventy years old. I probably read it in an anthology. It felt old even when I read it.

Here's what I remember: A baby was raised completely isolated from contact with the outside environment and other people, rather like the real-world story of the boy in a bubble. But either his father or perhaps a group of scientists decided to do this because they believed this would create a perfect human. And it worked.

The boy grew up to be the brightest person on Earth. People came to him with every problem that couldn't be solved. He was completely healthy and didn't seem to grow old.

And that's as much as I can recall. I know something bad happened, but what it was, I have no idea.

**Edit: I think this story is from the 1920s and no later.**

Comment: You're not thinking about [_The First Men_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Men) by Howard Fast, right? That one's only 55 years old...

Comment: It sounds a bit like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waldo_(short_story) , although the premise of that story was a bit different. Still [snip]spoilers[/snip] ...

Comment: @MrLister, That story sounds fascinating, but it doesn't quite match up with what I remember. There was only one child and the plot was simpler.

Comment: @MarkBannister, "Waldo" is a great and classic story, but not what I was thinking of. The story in my mind is even older than Heinlein's and feels antique.

Comment: Sounds more like the merging of two different John travolta movies.